# How to use map2 with vectors of unequal length

Tags: r, purrr

#### The problem

I am trying to calculate the income tax payable on incomes between $1 and $200,000 with increments of $100 (2000 values).

I have scraped information on the tax rates resulting in a list of 34 data frames.

I have a function that calculates tax payable based on income and applicable rates.

Using that function I want to produce a vector showing tax payable:

1. for each income level (2000 values)
2. for each set of (34 sets of rates)

It would great if I could return this output in a data frame/tibble.

#### The data

```
#This scrapes the website of the tax administrator and returns a list of tidy data frames showing tax rates for income years between 2016 and 1983
url <- "https://www.ato.gov.au/Rates/Individual-income-tax-for-prior-years/"
pit_sch <- url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_table() %>%
  setNames(., url %>%
             read_html() %>%
             html_nodes("caption") %>%
             html_text()) %>% 
  map(.%>%
    mutate(`Tax on this income` = gsub(",", "", `Tax on this income`), 
            cumm_tax_amt = str_extract(`Tax on this income`, "(?<=^\\$)\\d+") %>% as.numeric(), 
            tax_rate = str_extract(`Tax on this income`, "\\d+.(\\d+)?(?=(\\s+)?c)") %>% as.numeric(), 
            threshold = str_extract(`Tax on this income`, "(?<=\\$)\\d+$") %>% as.numeric()
           )
    ) %>%
  map(~drop_na(.x, threshold)) %>% 
  map(function(x) { mutate_each(x, funs(replace(., is.na(.), 0))) })

#Defining income 
income <- seq(from = 1, to = 200000, by = 100)

#The function for calculating tax payable
tax_calc <- function(data, income) {
  i <-tail(which(income >= data[, 5]), 1)
  if (length(i) > 0) 
    return(((income - data[i,5]) * (data[i,4]/100)) + data[i,3])
  else
    return(0)
}
```

#### My attempt

```
> map2(pit_sch, income, tax_calc)
Error: Mapped vectors must have consistent lengths:
* `.x` has length 34
* `.y` has length 2000
    enter code here
```

Comment: As the error suggested, you need both elements to have the same length `map2` or `Map` (from `baser R`) works on corresponding elements of lists or vectors, so if the length is different, it throws error as it is expecting both to be same length

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To properly distinguish between different `income` and years for which this is calculated. I would suggest let `tax_calc` function return a `tibble` with `income` and `tax` calculation.

```
library(tidyverse)

tax_calc <- function(data, income) {
   i <-tail(which(income >= data[, 5]), 1)
  if (length(i) > 0) 
    return(tibble(income = income, 
          tax = (income - data[i,5]) * (data[i,4]/100) + data[i,3]))
  else
    return(tibble(income = income, tax = 0))
}
```

Since you want `tax_calc` for all `income` for each `pit_sch` you can use

```
map(pit_sch,~map_df(income, tax_calc, data = .)) %>%  bind_rows(., .id = "id")
```

---

Checking it for `tail(income)` we get

```
map(pit_sch,~map_df(tail(income), tax_calc, data = .)) %>%  bind_rows(., .id = "id")

# A tibble: 204 x 3
#   id                             income    tax
#   <chr>                           <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 Resident tax rates for 2016-17 199401 62962.
# 2 Resident tax rates for 2016-17 199501 63007.
# 3 Resident tax rates for 2016-17 199601 63052.
# 4 Resident tax rates for 2016-17 199701 63097.
# 5 Resident tax rates for 2016-17 199801 63142.
# 6 Resident tax rates for 2016-17 199901 63187.
# 7 Resident tax rates for 2015-16 199401 63277.
# 8 Resident tax rates for 2015-16 199501 63322.
# 9 Resident tax rates for 2015-16 199601 63367.
#10 Resident tax rates for 2015-16 199701 63412.
# … with 194 more rows
```